# How can I get Jquery event listener to work with div link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="post-<?php echo $i++; ?>"></div>
    <div class="like-icon-container">
        <span class="icon-thumbs-up"></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

And a listener to pick out the ID of the link that was clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
</script>
```

The script does NOT work in the above example where I'm trying to link the icon that is in the div (it's not an image, but a font icon rendered in css). But the script works if I add text in the first div like this:

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="post-<?php echo $i++; ?>">asdfasdf</div>
    <div class="like-icon-container">
        <span class="icon-thumbs-up"></span>
    </div>
</a>
```

How can I get this to work without adding text in the first div?

Comment: Thanks, but I need the DIV to be clickable. How can I make this work so that the DIV is clickable link?

Comment: You shouldn't wrap the div with a. You can add the a inside and make the box with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put div inside an anchor element. I'd suggest you to do it like this:

```
<div id="post-<?php echo $i++; ?>" class="clickable like-icon-container"><span class="icon-thumbs-up"></span></div>
```

CSS (pointer cursor):

```
.clickable { cursor: pointer; }
```

And then the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        // alternatively:
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work. The ID's come back as 'undefined'.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about `attr`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).children(":first").attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

see

#### JS Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to put a   b/w the div instead of text if this doesn`t work apply a class to the div(s) and get a function call at click of that class

```
        <div id="post-<?php echo $i++; ?>" class="isclicked"></div>
        <div class="like-icon-container">
            <span class="icon-thumbs-up"></span>
        </div>


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".isclicked").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
```